# How to use function caller variable in the function like parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters

In C# I can create a function like `public static string ToUpper(this string str){ str.ToUpper(); }`

I want overwrite the string replace function, for example:

```
var str = "test";
str.myReplace("var1", "var2");
```

How to can I get `str` variable in `myReplace`, like orivinal `replace` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could extend the `String` type in javascript

```
String.prototype.myReplace = function (var1, var2) {
    // Here "this" will refer to the current value the method was invoked on
    return this.replace(var1, var2);
};
```

and then you could invoke the method like that:

```
var str = "test";
var result = str.myReplace("var1", "var2");
```

Comment: sorry for my bad expression, I need create extension method for javascript

Comment: I have updated my answer to illustrate how you could achieve this.